# Customised Tabbar on StoryBoards in ios7

Tags: ios

I am doing the requirement that I need to fully Customized the `UITabbar` and shows the Actual images on `UITabbarItems`.

By Googling I get the code below its worked fine,

```
UIImage *musicImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"music.png"];
UIImage *musicImageSel = [UIImage imageNamed:@"musicSel.png"];

musicImage = [musicImage imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
musicImageSel = [musicImageSel imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];

self.musicViewController.tabBarItem = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Music" image:musicImage selectedImage:musicImageSel];
```

But I am not using any code in my app and I used only `StoryBoard` is there any way to get the actual images on Tabbar item?

Thankyou

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can set up the picture in your tabBar via the `StoryBoard`. Follow these steps:

1. First you should import the desired picture in your project (a simple drag and drop is enough, but be sure the `copy item into destination group's folder is checked)
2. In your `StoryBoard`you should have something like this (`UITabBarController` and his sons controllers):

[image: StoryBoard type TabBar]

3. Select the linked son controller and update its `Image` variable in the section `Bar Item` in the `Attribute inspector`:

[image: Update tabBarItem pic via storyboard]

**tips: you should import your picture at the following format: mypicture.png-22x22px, mypicture@2x.png-44x44px**

Answer (score 0):

[image]

1. Select the view controller you wish to set a tab bar item image for.
2. Click on its tab bar item (The circle labelled "First" in the screenshot.)
3. Set the image in the attributes inspector on the right.

Comment: But Still My Image in the Tabbar item should not in the Actual Formet, It Should be Like an iCon Image